# Сделать по центру

Tags: html, css

Приветствую!
Как не пробовал сделать по центру - не получается, пробовал элементарными способами, думаю спрашивать не нужно какими.
Ссылка на  [сайт](http://nloshop.com.ua/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

```css
.pstrnav {
  height: 30px;
  clear: left;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.pstrnav li {
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    margin-left: 7px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pstrnav">
  <ul style="display: inline-block">
    <li><a class="pstr-active" href="?page=1">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li><a class="pstr-next" href="?page=2">&gt;</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Ура! Спасибо Вам большое! Если не трудно, подскажите потому что я не могу вопросов больше задавать. У меня меню которое открывается списком вниз, при закрытии не открывается ещё раз, только если перезагрузить страницу...

Comment: Скорее всего, меню управляется с помощью js. Там и смотрите что не так. Если ответ решил заданый вопрос, отметьте его